# How to search Wikipedia for all pages of a certain thing?

Tags: wikipedia

I'm trying to find a list of all Wikipedia pages for "martial artists" (persons).

One example is the [Wikipedia page for Cain Velasquez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cain_Velasquez).

**All of these pages have an infobox template named "martial artist", so if there is any way to search for all pages with a specific infobox this would answer the question just as well.**

Any search technique would be acceptable if it could be a complete list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the page for the Infobox Template, the "What links here" link in the toolbox will tell you all of the pages that use that template. In this case...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Template:Infobox_martial_artist

Comment: Wow, beautiful answer - thanks.